# React Native build doesn't embed bundle file

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, aar

I'm developing an android library (packaged as .aar), using the `com.android.library` plugin. I have hooked in react native to my activity using the instructions provided in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-android.html.

However, when i run `gradlew.bat build` in my project, the generated package `./build/outputs/arr/{projectname-(debug/release)}.aar` doesn't contain the bundle `index.android.bundle` therefore react native fails to find it.

Is there any other steps that I need to do to get the bundle generated and packaged using gradle?

Thanks

Comment: were you able to create aar file , and use in native project?

Answer (score 7):

You need to override `jsBundleDir` in your `app/build.gradle` since the `assets` directory of an android library project is `${buildDir}/intermediates/bundles/${targetPath}/assets` instead of `${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${targetPath}`

For example, in your `app/build.gradle`, add the following lines

```
project.ext.react = [
    jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/bundles/debug/assets",
    jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/bundles/release/assets",
]
```